# Accessing variables inside function x in function z

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where the DOM element is stored within the variable, within its own function I can then refer to this var to change it. However in other functions I am unable to do this.. 
How can I access DOMtime from the second function?

It should be noted that the first function will always be called before the second function, so `DOMtime` will always be ready.

```
$('.page').on("click", '.button', function () {
    var DOMtime = $(this).parent().siblings().find('span.time')[0];
    $(DOMtime).text("test");

});
$('.modal').on("click", '.save', function () {

    $(DOMtime).text("another test");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare it on the upper scope

```
var DOMTime;

$('.page').on("click", '.button1', function () {
    DOMtime = $(this).parent().siblings().find('span.time')[0];
    $(DOMtime).text("test");

});
$('.modal').on("click", '.button2', function () {

    $(DOMtime).text("another test");
```

Please take not that if click is triggered on a .button2 before .button1 `DOMTime` will still be `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a global variable for accessing DOMtime. Try define it first as a global variable

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this instead?

```
$(function() {

    var DOMtime = $(this).parent().siblings().find('span.time')[0];

    $('.page').on("click", '.button1', function() {

        DOMtime.text("test");

    });

    $('.modal').on("click", '.button2', function() {

        DOMtime.text("another test");

    });

});
```

Comment: Because `this` does not match with the event's `this`

Comment: the 2nd line `this` refers to which row .button1 they have clicked.. (sorry I should have mentioned there is multiple buttons) [I'll change it].

Answer (score 0):

This is to do with *scope* and *closure*. The general idea is, you will need to `var` what you want to share in an ancestor scope;

```
var foo; // variable to share
function a() {
    foo = 1;
}
function b() {
    return foo;
}
a();
b(); // 1
```

If you don't want to pollute the namespace you're working in, you can use an *IIFE*, but remember to `return` the things you want out of it so they continue to exist/be referenceable;

```
var something = (function () { // IIFE starts, contents in own namespace
    var x = false; // this won't be referenceable outside the IIFE
    function something() { // some function
        return x = !x;
    }
    return something; // now return it so it can exist outside the IIFE
}()); // invoke IIFE
something(); // true
something(); // false
something(); // true
// but
x; // undefined (or ReferenceError in strict mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a global variable to access it anywhere in your others fonctions:

```
var globalvar = "";
$('.page').on("click", '.button1', function () {
    var DOMtime = $(this).parent().siblings().find('span.time')[0];
    $(DOMtime).text("test");
    globalvar = $(this);

});
$('.modal').on("click", '.button2', function () {

    $(DOMtime).text("another test");
    alert(globalvar);
 }
```

Then you'll be able to get the dometime variable anywhere ;)